# How to compare the variance of two time series?

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics, f-test

I would like to answer whether two time series have the same variance. Initially, I used an F test to compare the two series variation. However, the two series appear to be skewed which would violate the normality assumption.  What method can I use to compare the variance of these two time series?

Year,A,B

1921,286,243

1922,282,268

1923,278,266

1924,278,284

1925,274,292

1926,270,296

1927,264,277

1928,261,276

1929,251,258

1930,254,264

1931,271,299

1932,286,303

1933,281,297

1934,284,284

1935,281,271

1936,278,259